# Quickly compute the convolution product of two Probability Density Functions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

Suppose I have the probability density function on some sufficiently large range with small enough inter-spacing. I now would like to compute the convolution product of these two  probability density functions as efficient as possible, at the moment I have the following function:

```
def convolve_PDF(PDF1, PDF2, delta):
    conv_PDF = np.empty(len(PDF1))
    for n in range(len(conv_PDF)):
        conv_PDF[n] = np.trapz(PDF1[0:(n+1)] * PDF2[n::-1], dx = delta)
    return conv_PDF

delta = 0.001
s_range = np.arange(0,100,delta)
PDF1 = scipy.stats.expon(scale = 100).cdf(s_range)
PDF2 = scipy.stats.gamma(a = 1).cdf(s_range)
PDF_convol = convolve_PDF(PDF1, PDF2, delta)
```

here `delta` is the interspacing.

As you can probably tell, this code is very slow and I was wondering how I can speed this up?

Comment: np.convolve ? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html

Comment: What is the shape of `PDF1` and `PDF2`? and a nominal value for `delta`??   Would it be possible to include a portion of the pdf arrays that could be used for *testing*.  ... [mcve]

Comment: 1. I changed my code to use `np.convolve` but something is unexpectedly going wrong, I use `PDF_convolve = np.convolve(PDF1,PDF2,'same') * delta`, but for some reason this is not giving me the same results as before (am still looking into it).
2. I adapted the question so that it has a minimal example

Comment: @HolyMonk You probably need 'full', not 'same'. Also, depending on your numpy/scipy version, you may want to use fftconvolve for speed (result is the same). Newer versions of convolve use fftconvolvee automatically in most situations.

Comment: A faster algorithm (using FFTs) is available in SciPy: [`scipy.signal.fftconvolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html#scipy.signal.fftconvolve).

Comment: @PaulPanzer I can consider using `full`, but I would rather not as I need to convolute iteratively (around 100 times), so if I use `full`, I'm afraid my size will blow up?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Good to know, thank you!

Comment: @HolyMonk If performance becomes a problem there are two things you can do. (1) fftconvolve (2) use 'full' and then look at the result and truncate bins that fall below some threshold before the next iteration. If you just truncate indiscriminately which is what 'same' does you can't control the error.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Okay I will try to do so, thank you.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Reading up on `np.convolve` it is clear to me that I should just cut out the second half of what the full mode is returning, thank you!

Comment: @HolyMonk I can't say I follow. But that doesn't necessarily mean it's wrong. So if you know what you're doing go ahead.

Comment: @PaulPanzer It gives me the result I was looking for, only like 1000 times faster than before so thank you!

Comment: @HolyMonk Btw. if you feel your solution may be useful for others, it is perfectly acceptable to answer one's own question.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I will, but I am not yet 100% satisfied with the result but will see how to fix this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this can be solved quickly by using `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`. In particular the following can be used in each iteration:

```
PDF_convolve = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(PDF1, PDF2)[0:len(PDF1)] * delta
PDF_convolve = PDF_convolve / np.trapz(PDF_convolve, dx = delta)
```

we divide by `np.trapz(PDF_convolve, dx = delta)` as small errors may lead to `PDF_convolve` not integrating to one but rather to some value close to one, this error is then magnified each convolution.